# CUPS central server and multiple slaves

Tags: linux, debian, cups

I have a central CUPS printing server in headquarters (ip in range 10.2.x.x/16) and a remote CUPS server in an office (ip in range 10.5.x.x/16). Both servers have full access by VPN.

I want to use the CUPS server in headquarters as primary server and if I add a printer in the server, share the printer to the remote office CUPS server automatically, is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it *should* work **IF**:

On each server:

Does `ip route` show a route for the other server?

Can you `tcping` or `hping` `TCP port 631` on the other server?

Does each server's CUPS Admin page (`http://localhost:631/admin`, use your login ID and password, when prompted) have checkmarks beside "`Share printers connected to this system`" and "`Aĺlow printing from the Internet`" and "`Allow remote  administration`". Click "`Change Settings.`"